# Magento jquery/prototype conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototypejs, conflict

I'm trying to implement Salvattore.js on a Magento website I'm working on.

It works fine on page load but if I resize the browser window it breaks. I'm almost certain it's caused by a conflict between Salvattore.js and prototype.js but I can't pin point the issue to fix it.

Has anyone else tried implementing salvattore.js on a Magento website??

All help & comments welcome!!

[Error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mY0kL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery and Prototype will not conflict until you use $ as selector for both these libraries. use $.noConflict() in jQuery and use jQuery to invoke all calls to jQuery like jQuery("#id").hide(). Reserve $ for prototype.

If your problem is still not solved then conflict between jQuery and prototype was not an issue. something else is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help and advice, but I've used the no conflict and  all of instances of jQuery and prototype are working side by side. The problem seems to be with the salvattore.js plugin and prototype. I have removed prototype as a test and salvattore works fine. Could it be that prototype is changing a function which salvattore.js relys on?

Comment: Can you tell me what is the error? Is it related to any array operation.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading the prototype to 1.7.2 it solves the issue for  me , but i am still testing with magento in-case of any issue

The root cause of this is that the Salvattore  is deferring to the native implementation of Array.map if it exists, but, as noted above, the problem is that Prototype has already overwritten the native Array.map implementation with its own.

The fix lies in updating to Prototype 1.7.1, which changed some of its internals so that functions like Array.map support the function signatures of the native implementations, and so (most) errors like this don't occur. You'll need to upgrade your version of Prototype to at least 1.7.1 to avoid this problem, though you should consider upgrading to Prototype 1.7.2, the latest version with better performance and quite a few bug fixes